# What's wrong with the coefficients in this linked list implementation of polynomial addition?

Tags: java, linked-list, polynomials

I use linked list to implement polynomial in Java, every node in the linked list contains two int values(coefficient and exponent) and a pointer next.

```
public class Node {
    public int coef;  
    public int exp;  
    public Node next = null;  

    public Node() {
        coef = 0;
        exp = 0;
    }

    public Node(int coef, int exp) {
        this.coef = coef;
        this.exp = exp;
    } 
}
```

The following polynomial addition method takes two head nodes and returns the head node of the result linked list.

```
public class PolynList {
    public static Node add(Node link1, Node link2) {
        Node itr1 = link1;
        Node itr2 = link2;
        while (itr2.next != null) {
            Node newNode = new Node(itr2.next.coef, itr2.next.exp);
            itr2 = itr2.next;
//            System.out.println(newNode.coef);

            while (itr1.next != null) {
                if (itr1.next.exp < itr2.exp) {
                    itr1 = itr1.next;
                } else {
                    if (itr1.next.exp == itr2.exp) {
                        itr1.next.coef += itr2.coef;
                    } else {
                        newNode.next = itr1.next;
                        itr1.next = newNode;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (itr1.next == null) {
                itr1.next = itr2;
            }
        }
        return link1.next;
    }
}
```

Result shows the coefficients of the result polynomial are not correct. In addition, I found "System.out.println(newNode.coef);" has been executed many times, way more than the expected while loop iterations. I do not understand what happens here.

I tried this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node link1 = new Node();
        Node a1 = new Node(2, 1);
        Node a2 = new Node(3, 3);
        Node a3 = new Node(1, 4);
        link1.next = a1;
        a1.next = a2;
        a2.next = a3;
        a3.next = null;

        Node link2 = new Node();
        Node b1 = new Node(5, 2);
        Node b2 = new Node(2, 4);
        Node b3 = new Node(1, 5);
        Node b4 = new Node(3, 6);
        link2.next = b1;
        b1.next = b2;
        b2.next = b3;
        b3.next = b4;
        b4.next = null;

        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).coef);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).exp);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.coef);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.exp);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.next.coef);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.next.exp);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.next.next.coef);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.next.next.exp);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.next.next.next.coef);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.next.next.next.exp);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.next.next.next.next.coef);
        System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2).next.next.next.next.next.exp);
    }
}
```

The result is here:

```
2
1
15
2
3
3
15
4
256
5
6144
6
```

This is what I expected:

```
2
1
5
2
3
3
3
4
1
5
3
6
```

Comment: Please explain the reasoning behind your inner `while` loop, and how that compares to how you see it *actually* work when you use a debugger.

Comment: code is calling `add()` way too often - once for every `System.out.println(PolynList.add(link1, link2). ...` - every call it is changing `link1`, so `link2` get added again and again. Do call `add()` only once, before printing; and then print the result stored in `link1` or use another variable to store the result from `add()` || `return link1.next;` is kind of inconsistent - input both stat with an *empty* node, returned list will not

Answer (score 0):

I see are several issues with your code: method `add` modifies the polynomials given in input, so you cannot reuse them after the call, you should have nested loops, Your polynomials have an extra node at the beginning.

Try something like this:

```
public static Node add(Node link1, Node link2) {
    Node first = null;
    Node last = null;
    while (link1 != null && link2 != null) {
        Node newNode;
        if (link1.exp == link2.exp) {
            newNode = new Node(link1.coef + link2.coef, link1.exp);
            link1 = link1.next;
            link2 = link2.next;
        } else if (link1.exp < link2.exp) {
            newNode = new Node(link1.coef, link1.exp);
            link1 = link1.next;
        } else {
            newNode = new Node(link2.coef, link2.exp);
            link2 = link2.next;
        }
        if (last == null) {
            first = last = newNode;
        } else {
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
    }
    while (link1 != null) {
        Node newNode = new Node(link1.coef, link1.exp);
        link1 = link1.next;
        if (last == null) {
            first = last = newNode;
        } else {
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
    }
    while (link2 != null) {
        Node newNode = new Node(link2.coef, link2.exp);
        link2 = link2.next;
        if (last == null) {
            first = last = newNode;
        } else {
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

and then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node a1 = new Node(2, 1);
    Node a2 = new Node(3, 3);
    Node a3 = new Node(1, 4);
    Node link1 = a1;
    a1.next = a2;
    a2.next = a3;
    a3.next = null;

    Node b1 = new Node(5, 2);
    Node b2 = new Node(2, 4);
    Node b3 = new Node(1, 5);
    Node b4 = new Node(3, 6);
    Node link2 = b1;
    b1.next = b2;
    b2.next = b3;
    b3.next = b4;
    b4.next = null;

    Node sum = PolynList.add(link1, link2);
    System.out.println(sum.coef);
    System.out.println(sum.exp);
    System.out.println(sum.next.coef);
    System.out.println(sum.next.exp);
    System.out.println(sum.next.next.coef);
    System.out.println(sum.next.next.exp);
    System.out.println(sum.next.next.next.coef);
    System.out.println(sum.next.next.next.exp);
    System.out.println(sum.next.next.next.next.coef);
    System.out.println(sum.next.next.next.next.exp);
    System.out.println(add(link1, link2).next.next.next.next.next.coef);
    System.out.println(add(link1, link2).next.next.next.next.next.exp);
}
```